# Appropriate way for ui testing in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso

I'm a beginner in ui test. At first step my ui test, tests the app from beginning to the end non-stop with using all features, after that test finishes.

But I think there must be a more convenient way, for example testing all activities at seperate tests etc.

How should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Having one massive test is not a sustainable or reliable approach.  If feature A and feature B are completely independent, and the part of the test fails for feature A, feature B's test code would never be reached since the test has already failed.

Separate your tests more into features.  Features that are independent or could fail on their own should have their own test. Check out the [Google single activity Espresso guide](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html)